# Generics passing type parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, generics, dependency-injection

I'm using dependancy injection from Unity. i..e Unity.Mvc5. I fetch all types from the various assemblies

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(string.Format("{0}\\{1}", AppStartPath, containerElement.InterfaceAssembly));
Assembly assembly2 = Assembly.LoadFrom(string.Format("{0}\\{1}", AppStartPath, containerElement.ConcreteClassAssembly));
Type type = assembly.GetType(containerElement.InterfaceName);
Type type2 = assembly2.GetType(containerElement.ConcreteClass);
```

Now the following works when I pass the types:

```
  container.RegisterType<IWarehouseBinController, WarehouseBinController>();
```

But this doesn't

```
container.RegisterType<type.GetTypeInfo().GetType(), type2.GetTypeInfo().GetType()>();
```

Anyone know why or how to resolve it? Basically I want to use this in an ASP.Net MVC site.

Comment: A `Type` instance is not a generic arguments, which is why it doesn't work. I believe there's a [method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/ee650414(v%3dpandp.10)) which takes `Type` objects instead of generic arguments.

Comment: Yeah. It is a duplicate

Answer (score 0):

refereeing to this [link](https://www.konda.eu/csharp-dependency-injections-and-automatic-registration-with-autofac/) you can see how you can do dynamic registration of all types 
of dependencies even the generic type , but please note that example using autofac library but i believe all of them same .

```
  var builder = new Autofac.ContainerBuilder();
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var assemblyTypes = assembly.GetTypes();

foreach (var type in assemblyTypes)
{
    // Ignore interfaces
    if (type.IsInterface)
        continue;

    var typeInterfaces = type.GetInterfaces();

    // Class should implement IDependecy or ISingletonDependency
    if (!typeInterfaces.Any(i => i.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IDependency))))
        continue;

    var registration = builder.RegisterType(type).AsImplementedInterfaces();

    if (typeInterfaces.Any(i => i.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(ISingletonDependency))))
        registration.SingleInstance();
    else
        registration.InstancePerRequest();
}
```